# Is there a workaround the sudo permission?

Tags: software-installation, sudo, root

I just got assigned the task to install and compare two software packages for linux but I don't have sudo permissions to do so. Is there a work around it? Is this even possible?

Another question which cross my mind while typing this is, I have the permission to create a file, right ? Which every user has. Installing a program is just like copying some code base, executing it which also makes another file and you just run that executable. What is so special in installing that I need root permission?

I have never taken a CS class before. 
I have almost just lurked the internet for my complete CS knowledge.

Comment: Installing software can lead to system security vulnerabilities. This may be intentional or unintentional but both are good reasons as to why you need root permissions to install software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the root password (if available) or you need to be setup to use sudo by your system administrator.

There is no *workaround* for this. Not being able to gain root access to a system unless intended is essential for the system's security, see also [Privilege Escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation).

To the second part of your question: You can create files in your home directory and some other (mostly temporary) folders. A system wide installation that can be accessed by all should not be possible for you if the system is set up in a default manner.

In many cases you can still install the software into your home directory, into some path (aka "prefix") like `~/.local/`. How this is done depends on the specific software and your installation method, but you might have a chance to install it for your own usage at least.

Depending on the permissions set by the administrator or the OS defaults, others may even be able to access your home directory - although in most cases this is not the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

you can install software in your home directory and execute it there.

this is how "steam" works. etc...

if the software needs access to restriced resources (eg: secret files, or privileged ports, hardware devices) the it probably will not be usable.